Calling python function using Matlab error: Unable to resolve the name
I have a python file. The name of the file is final_output.py which contains one function text_recognizer. When I try to call this function using Matlab script it throws me error message.
Unable to resolve the name 'py.final_output.text_recognizer'.

Error in NER_PM (line 16)

pyOut = py.final_output.text_recognizer(model_path, text);

I share the code block here which I tried to run in Matlab,
pe = pyenv;
disp(pe);

path_add = fileparts(which('final_output.py'));
if count(py.sys.path, path_add) == 0
    insert(py.sys.path, int64(0), path_add);
end

model_path = 'D:\\output\\model-best';
text = 'Roses are red';

pyOut = py.final_output.text_recognizer(model_path, text);

entity_labels = cell(pyOut);
disp(entity_labels);

Any help will be appreciated.

You might need to import the module first?
